# In Strider, how do I deactivate the second water valve?

Tags: strider

I'm not really sure but I think the game just glitched on me. I reached the room where the switch is, but no matter how I hit it, the valve won't deactivate. Did I miss anything? Here's a [video of my problem](https://youtu.be/U3GabEKottM).